# mysql Best way to get result

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Here are my tables

**Note**
  This tables are for example only

**Posts**

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   id  |title | desc  |  uid  |status |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   1   |  a   | aaaa  |   1   |   1   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   2   |  b   | bbbb  |   1   |   1   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+   3   |  c   | cccc  |   2   |   1   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Cats**

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  id   | name |parent | status |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1    | cat1 |   0   |   1    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  2    | cat2 |   0   |   1    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Tags**

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  id   | name  | title |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1    | tag1  |ttitle |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  2    | tag2  |title2 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Linked_data**

Linked as one 2 multi relation ship

Link Name
 postid
 cat_or_tag_id

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ name    |  r1         | r2|
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ cat     |  1          | 1 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ cat     |  1          | 2 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ tag     |  1          | 2 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to get posts with its cats and tags

what's the best way to do this

**The only way i know now** 
    is get posts then foreach post get its cats and tags

Comment: is this the definite table structure? I would strongly recommend to change that...

Comment: and in `linked_data`, what is r1 and what is r2? could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes my table structure like this structure , why You recommend to cchange this , and whats the best way to use multi cats and tags for posts

Comment: Link Name
postid
cat_or_tag_id

Comment: it depends on how many rows you have in your database, and if you care for performance, but there might be 2 major issues. eggyal gave you the correct query, this query needs 2 levels for the joins (first join with `linked_data` and then `linked_data` with `cats` and `tags`), which can become slow. Also, in your place I would use two tables of linked data, one for cats and one for tags. It is faster and more flexible and you will get less headache later on. Also be aware of the right indexing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Posts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(Cats.name) AS Cats, GROUP_CONCAT(Tags.name) AS Tags
FROM   Posts
  LEFT JOIN Linked_data ON Linked_data.r1 = Posts.id
  LEFT JOIN Cats        ON Linked_data.r2 =  Cats.id AND Linked_data.name = 'cat'
  LEFT JOIN Tags        ON Linked_data.r2 =  Tags.id AND Linked_data.name = 'tag'
GROUP BY Posts.id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/225fc/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
select p.title, c.name , t.name  from posts p
inner join (select group_concat(c1.name), c1.id  from cats c1 group by c1.id ) c on p.id = c.id
inner join (select group_concat(t1.name), t1.id  from tags t1 group by t1.id ) t on p.id = t.id
```